# How to create an object of a class from another class in PHP?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have been trying to create an object of a PHPMailer() class in another class but it just doesn't work.

I have included all the files like in my main index.php file

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require "assets/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
require "assets/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php";
require "assets/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php";
```

these have been imported successfully because if I declare

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
```

in this file then the mail object is created.

But, I want to this in a specific function of another class. I have a class **Projects** and in it, I have defined a **public static function** *do_request()* which sends an SQL query to a database. This function works perfectly fine, but now I want to send an email whenever this function is called. For that, I created a new **public function** *send_email()* in the same class and I call it from the public static function **do_request()**. In the **send_email()** function when I declare

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
```

the code crashes and my object is not created anymore. Can anyone tell me what might be wrong here?

Comment: Could you complete your question with the stacktrace for us to help out please ?

Comment: Please, read about autoloading (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) or use composer to require libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you're getting a crash, the first place to look is your web server's error log.

In the absence of your actual code or any error messages, we can only guess at the cause.

If you have those `require` statements inside a function that you all, it will fail the second time you call it because you're loading duplicate classes. This is also a very good reason to learn to use composer, as it means you don't have to worry about loading classes manually.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I am not sure which error log you are referring to here. There is the networks log and the console log but none of them give me any information on the PHP code. The `require` statements are in the global context and not inside a function. But the class `Projects` is in a separate file that I include in index.php using require, and in this separate file I can't define the object for the PHPMailer() even globally. In index.php I can create the object and it works. So now I think the problem is that I cannot use PHPMailer() in a file other than the one I define it in.

Comment: Your web server (apache, nginx, IIS or whatever) will have an error log where PHP errors are stored; you need to find where it is. `use` statements are local to the file they appear in, so every file that creates a PHPMailer instance also needs to have a `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;` line. The same does not apply to the `requires`; you can use `require_once` safely, but it's far better to use composer to manage this. Again though, we're all just guessing without seeing your code and any error messages – search for how to find them.

Comment: I think the problem was with the `use ` statements and after adding them the code works now. Thanks a lot for your help!